# (firebase functions) Error: Forbidden Your client does not have permission to get URL /

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have problem when invoking deployed function in firebase. I have an editor role in the firebase project and when I deployed functions, didn't have any problem with invoking them. When I deployed a new function yesterday, I got the error message that says

> Error: Forbidden
>
> Your client does not have permission to get URL / < Function Name > from this server.

Nothing has been changed to my role. It is strange that since yesterday, whatever function I deployed, threw those errors.

In gcp console/cloud functions, where you can see permissions of the function that was selected, I've noticed that "cloud functions invoker" was not assigned to that function. I thought this should be added to any function by default as long as I have an editor access but strangely it does not add them anymore. other functions that were deployed since yesterday have the same issue

any suggestions or advices will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Contact Firebase support for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Thank you Doug Stevenson. Got the answer from firebase team.

Comment: Official info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#invoke_an_http_function

Comment: How to make functions public (if not through Firebase CLI v7.7.0+): https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_http_function_invocation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So here's the answer from the firebase team

> The issue you are experiencing is likely caused by the fact that after January 15, 2020, Google Cloud Functions automatically creates HTTP functions to be >private by default.

> Please, update the CLI, by running the following command:

`npm install -g firebase-tools`

> This will ensure that future HTTP functions that are created will be publicly accessible.

> Lastly, for the existing functions that has the permission issues, you will need >to manually set a function to public using Cloud Console or gcloud CLI.

> If you have any questions or you are still facing this issue, please, don’t >hesitate to write back.

edited*
There could be several reasons to cause this issue.

1. check your function endpoint url make sure there's no typo or space
2. In the gcp console, make sure you have permission to invoke function https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list?project=<YOUR_PROJECT_ID>
3. If the above two are checked, delete your function and redeploy your them again

Comment: I hadn't read the third point, but what did work for me was exactly that. I simply `deleted my functions and redeploy them`.

The details of my case are here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72420245/9791840

Answer (score 10):

- [Please Review](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation) Allowing unauthenticated function invocation

As of January 15, 2020, HTTP functions require authentication by default. You can specify whether a function allows unauthenticated invocation at or after deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How would you specify "whether a function allows unauthenticated invocation at or after deployment" ? wonder what command line you use to configure those settings. thank you

Comment: Go to the Google Cloud Console:
Go to Google Cloud Console https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list

1. Click the checkbox next to the function on which you want to grant access.

2. Click Show Info Panel in the top right corner to show the Permissions tab.

3. Click Add member.

4. In the New members field, type allUsers.

Select the role Cloud Functions > Cloud Functions Invoker from the Select a role drop-down menu.

Click Save.

Comment: thanks but this is after deployment configuration. And if you're an editor, it is not possible to change or grant access to other users in console window. As you mentioned, "You can specify whether a function allows unauthenticated invocation at...deployment" wondering what would be the command line at the time of deployment. thanks

Comment: Like you saved my life today. Lots of love!

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, you can't do this in Firebase, you have to go into the Google Cloud project which 'hosts' your firebase project. You can follow this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_http_function_invocation) by Google, and have a look at the screenshots below:

[image]

## You should see `Allow unauthenticated` now

[image]

Answer (score 3):

updating firebase-tools wasn't enough in my case because i already deployed that function and updating it didn't fix the issue, i had to delete it and deploy again

Answer (score 3):

To allow unauthenticated invocation of a function, you add the special allUsers member id to the function and grant it the Cloud Functions Invoker role:

[image]

You can limit domain access in your function, for example:

```
exports.myTest= async(req, res) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'foo.com');
  ...etc
```

Comment: `Principals of type allUsers and allAuthenticatedUsers cannot be added to this resource`

Answer (score 3):

I defined my Firebase cloud functions in typescript/JS and deploy using Firebase CLI. I got this error after customizing the deployment settings, and I fixed it by specifying `invoker="public"` - I did not need to dig into IAM settings or use the console or CLI to fix.

```js
export const serve = functions
  .region("us-west2")
  .runWith({
    invoker: "public",  // this is the magic line 
  })
  .https.onRequest(
    async (request: functions.Request, response: functions.Response) => {
   // ...
  })
```